# What's this brown gunk on my PCB?

Tags: pcb

I recently bought an old SM144 CRT monitor to play about with an Atari ST I found in the loft. It works for a little while, but it gives off a bit of a burning/ionising smell. After a few minutes if I turn off/on the monitor I get some striped lines like the following:

[image]

I took it apart to see if there was anything glaringly obvious. And something that immediately stood out to me was this brown gunk. Should I be worried? Any ideas what it is? It's in multiple places:

[image]

And:

[image]

Also, if anybody has any suggestions on what might cause the monitor to not work after turning off then on, I'm all ears.

Here're are the schematics:
[image]

And:
[image]

Comment: Please post schematics of the monitor.

Comment: Sure, @Andyaka I've updated the question. Also, here's a link if that's easier. https://archive.org/details/Atari_SM144_Schematic_undated

Comment: your question is about the glue ... schematics are not necessary ... please ask a question about the failure in a separate post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's glue. Or some other sort of adhesive.

It mechanically fixes large components to PCB, so they don't get loose from mechanical vibrations.

Comment: ahh, thank you, saved me going down a rabbit hole there.

Comment: Don't suppose you have any indication on what the issue might be with the lines when turning off then on the monitor?

Comment: Nope. Is the monitor being fed with any video signal, so does it get syncs or not? Is the video input disconnected or connected? Is the monitor properly connected to an earthed mains socket? Is the video cable properly connected, so the signal grounds make a good connection?

Comment: Yes it's connected to the atari st. It works fine until it's turned off then on, by the monitor.

Comment: @user3667111 A comment section on an answer is not the place to debug a circuit though...

Comment: @pipe yeah, apologies, I created a new question